# Rails hidden_field_tag integer auto converts to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, hidden-field

I have a form using a hidden_field_tag.  The value I put as a parameter in the hidden_field_tag is an integer but when it comes out on the other side it's a string.  Does hidden field tag auto convert this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer = yes
The real answer is it creates an input tag on the html side, the value you passed in as an integer gets set as value="your value here".. So anything in an input field will be a string.

Comment: k thanks, thought this was the case but couldn't find it spelled out anywhere so wanted to be sure